# Can I print a function and set it to a variable at the same time in Python?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, python-2.7

I'm wondering if it is possible to run the following piece of code while also capturing the resulting value into a variable at the same time. The code is as follows:

```
def nodupchoice():
    # For loop that creates a list named keys. It grabs 3 random keys from the dictionary word_drills
    keys = [x for x in random.sample(word_drills, 3)]
    # User is presented with a question. A value from the previous randomly selected keys is selected as the 'question'
    print "Question: ", word_drills[random.choice(keys)]
    # Set the variables key1, key2, & key3 to the 3 keys in the list 'keys'
    key1, key2, key3 = keys[0], keys[1], keys[2]
    # User is presented with 3 choices.
    print "\n\n(a)%s   (b)%s   (c)%s" % (key1, key2, key3)
    selection = raw_input("> ")
    print selection
    print correctvalue
```

The line of code is **print "Question: ", word_drills[random.choice(keys)]** . I wanted to put this result in a variable and run an if/else statement to see if the answer is correct or not. Thanks again.

Comment: Why can't you just set it to a variable and then print it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Er, yes? Just assign it to a variable:

```
question = word_drills[random.choice(keys)]
print question
```

Now the variable `question` remains available later.